# Include Join Paramater based on column value

Tags: sql, join, case

I am trying to do a conditional join based on the value of `[CURR MNBR]`, so if `[CURR MNBR]` is NULL, then I want to use `[Config] = 'Stock'`, otherwise use `[CURR MBR] IN...`

```
CREATE TABLE #raw_customer  
(
    [DECIMAL] decimal(20, 4),
    [WIDTH] decimal(20, 4),
    [LENGTH] decimal(20, 4),
    [SAE] varchar(10),
    [CURR MNBR] varchar(255),
    [AID] varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE #merged_products 
(
    [pID] int,
    [Thickness] decimal(20, 4),
    [Width] decimal(20, 4),
    [Length] decimal(20, 4),
    [Grade] varchar(10),
    [MNumber] varchar(255),
    [Config] varchar(255),
    [AID] varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO #raw_customer 
VALUES (0.299,  48, 100, 'XB0', NULL,       ''),
       (0.3,    60, 120, 'XB0', 'M723087',  ''),
       (0.25,   48, 140, 'GR1', 'M701283',  '906008314'),
       (0.25,   60, 140, 'Y45', NULL,       '008008314'),
       (0.125,  72, 205, 'GR7', 'M712390',  '005003468');
 
INSERT INTO #merged_products 
VALUES (1, 0.2990,  48.0000, 100.0000, 'XB0', NULL, 'Stock',     ''),
       (2, 0.3000,  60.0000, 120.0000, 'XB0', NULL,     'Stock', ''),
       (3, 0.2500,  48.0000, 140.0000, 'GR1', 'M701283',    'Stock', ''),
       (4, 0.2500,  60.0000, 140.0000, 'Y45', NULL,     'Raced', ''),
       (5, 0.1250,  72.0000, 205.0000, 'GR7', 'M712390',    'Raced', '005003468; 006008314; '),
       (6, 0.1250,  72.0000, 205.0000, 'GR7', 'M712390',    'Raced', '900751488; 006025951; 006022051');

SELECT
    mp.[pID],
    r.[DECIMAL],    mp.[Thickness],
    r.[WIDTH],      mp.[Width],
    r.[LENGTH],     mp.[Length],
    r.[SAE],        mp.[Grade],
    mp.[Config],    
    r.[CURR MNBR],  mp.[MNumber],
    r.[AID],        mp.[AID]
FROM 
    #raw_customer r
LEFT JOIN 
    #merged_products mp ON
    CAST(r.[DECIMAL] AS decimal(20,4))  = CAST(mp.[Thickness] AS decimal(20,4)) AND
    CAST(r.[WIDTH] AS decimal(20,4))    = CAST(mp.[Width] AS decimal(20,4)) AND
    CAST(r.[LENGTH] AS decimal(20,4))   = CAST(mp.[Length] AS decimal(20,4)) AND
    mp.[Config] = (
        CASE
            WHEN [CURR MNBR] IS NOT NULL THEN  'Stock'
            ELSE '' -- Would want this to accept any value
        END ) AND
    r.[SAE] = mp.[Grade]
GROUP BY
    mp.[pID], mp.[Thickness], mp.[Width], mp.[Length], mp.[Grade], mp.[MNumber], mp.[Config], mp.[AID], 
    r.[DECIMAL], r.[WIDTH], r.[LENGTH], r.[SAE], r.[CURR MNBR], r.[AID]
ORDER BY 
    r.[AID]
```

The result I am looking for is:

```
|pID    |DECIMAL|Thickness|WIDTH|Width   |LENGTH| Length    |SAE    |Grade  |Config  |CURR MNBR |MNumber  |AID          |AID
|1      | 0.299 |   0.2990| 48  | 48.0000| 100  | 100.0000  | 'XB0' | 'XB0' | 'Stock'|NULL      |NULL     | ''          |NULL|
|2      | 0.3   |   0.3000| 60  | 60.0000| 120  | 120.0000  | 'XB0' | 'XB0' | 'Stock'|'M723087' |NULL     | ''          |NULL|
|3      | 0.25  |   0.2500| 48  | 48.0000| 140  | 140.0000  | 'GR1' | 'GR1' | 'Stock'|'M701283' |'M701283'| '906008314' |NULL|
|4      | 0.25  |   0.2500| 60  | 60.0000| 140  | 140.0000  | 'Y45' | 'Y45' | 'Raced'|NULL      |NULL     | '008008314' |NULL|
|6      | 0.125 |   0.1250| 72  | 72.0000| 205  | 205.0000  | 'GR7' | 'GR7' | 'Raced'|'M712390' |'M712390'| '005003468' |'005003468; 006025951; 006022051'|
```

Comment: Just a note, I did not name any of these fields and I am unable to change the names.

Comment: CASE expressions must return scalar values. They're not IF statements from other languages. *(`CASE WHEN X=1 THEN A=B ELSE C=D END` won't parse, but `CASE WHEN X=1 THEN A ELSE C END = CASE WHEN X=1 THEN B ELSE D END`)*

Comment: Why does the rewrite check AID where as the original doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(
  (
    r.[CURR MNBR] IS NULL
    AND
    mp.[Config] = 'Stock'
  )
  OR
  (
    r.[CURR MNBR] IS NOT NULL
    AND
    r.[CURR MNBR] IN ( SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(mp.[MNumber],',')
  )
)
```

(The 'not null' line is actually not needed, as the IN can only ever be true if the value isn't NULL.)

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot of sense.  How would I handle the [AID].  Not all [AID]have a value or matching value, but in many cases I will get multiple matches, and the only difference is only one of them will have the [AID].  Not sure how to add "match the AID, but only if it has a match". Doing an AND will cut out many that would otherwise match fine, and doing something similar to what you did using an OR would defeat the purpose as I would still get the multiple matches.

Comment: @Dizzy49 I don't understand your description, I strongly suggest writing a [mre] for just the columns you're talking about *(a simplified example, as suggested here; [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952))*

Comment: I JUST added some example data, probably as you typed that.

Comment: In my example, the first line would match b/c the 123s all matched and the aid didn't so it didn't matter.  In the second there is no AID, so it didn't matter as the other fields all matched.  The last two lines have the same except for the AID is different.  Since the AID in the merged_product file matches the line in the raw file with the 321, we ONLY want that line.

Comment: @Dizzy49 That's not a [mre]. You need to show the results you want, you need to show what happens when there is no match, etc, etc. Please read the [mre] link in full

Comment: Rewrote to include example and expected result.

Answer (score -1):

'edited because of incorrect code pointed out by MatBailie'

```
declare @raw_customer table
(
    [DECIMAL] decimal(20, 4) not null,
    [WIDTH] decimal(20, 4) not null,
    [LENGTH] decimal(20, 4) not null,
    [SAE] varchar(10) not null,
    [CURR MNBR] varchar(255) null
)


declare @merged_products table
(
    [Thickness] decimal(20, 4) null,
    [Width] decimal(20, 4) null,
    [Length] decimal(20, 4) null,
    [Grade] varchar(10) null,
    [MNumber] varchar(255) null,
    [Config] varchar(255) null
)


insert into @raw_customer
select 1, 2, 3, 'some value', null union all
select 4, 5, 6, 'some value', 'curr mnbr'

insert into @merged_products
select 1, null, 3, 'grade 2', 'curr mnbr', '1, 2, 3, 4, 5' union all
select 1, 2, 3, 'some value', 'curr mnbr', 'stock' union all
select 1, 2, 3, 'grade 1', 'mnumber 2', 'some other stock'


select  
        r.[DECIMAL],
        r.[WIDTH],
        r.[LENGTH],
        r.[SAE],
        r.[CURR MNBR],
        mp.[Thickness],
        mp.[Width],
        mp.[Length],
        mp.[Grade],
        mp.[MNumber],
        mp.[Config]
from    @raw_customer r
                left outer join 
        @merged_products mp on
                    CAST(r.[DECIMAL] AS decimal(20,4)) = CAST(mp.[Thickness] AS decimal(20,4)) and
                    CAST(r.[WIDTH] AS decimal(20,4)) = CAST(mp.[Width] AS decimal(20,4)) and
                    CAST(r.[LENGTH] AS decimal(20,4)) = CAST(mp.[Length] AS decimal(20,4)) and
                    r.[SAE] = mp.[Grade] and
                    (
                        (r.[CURR MNBR] is null and mp.[Config] = 'stock') or
                        (r.[CURR MNBR] in(select value from string_split(mp.[MNumber],',' )))
                    )
```

Comment: Not for a LEFT OUTER JOIN

Comment: Please do not automatically decrement my solution.  Did you test it?

Comment: Your suggestion turns a LEFT join back to an INNER join. Down vote stands.

Comment: @MatBailie, thank you for doing your job.  I have reposted and provided you with credit in the edit, which contains testable code on SQL Server 2022

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).